# ASP.NET Core MVC IFormFile 415 unsupported media type

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, postman, fiddler

I have this service:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ChangePicture (IFormFile file)
{
    // doing something
    return Ok();
}
```

I test it in Postman, and it works fine.
I test it in Fiddler, and I get 415.
I post it in Angular using `FormData` and again I get 415.

I tried to compare requests using a compare software, and I see that headers are all `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----blablabla`

I'm stuck at this point on what might be wrong. A guess is that Fiddler and `FormData` use different serialization/encoding to transfer image files. But I'm not sure how can I debug that.

Comment: put `([FromForm] IFormFile file)...` in your action method

Comment: what kind of file are you trying to upload?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting [FromForm] or [FromBody] attribute to the file parameter